# Django - Userprofile field in my template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using UserProfile in my django app. It works very well in my view. But I am having some difficult to show the values in my template.

Variable that I am trying to print in my template:

**{{ request.user.get_profile().phone }}**

Error:

**Could not parse the remainder: '().phone' from 'request.user.get_profile().phone '**

Whats happened? How can I print mu userprofile variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
{{ request.user.get_profile.phone }}
```